# Spring Integration message processing partitioned by header information

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I want to be able to process messages with Spring Integration in parallel. The messages come from multiple devices and we need to process messages from the same device in sequential order but the devices can be processed in multiple threads. There can be thousands of devices so I'm trying to figure out how to assign processor based on mod of the device ID using Spring Integration's semantics as much as possible. What approach should I be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to generalize without knowing other requirements (transaction semantics etc) but probably the simplest approach would be a router sending messages to a number of `QueueChannel`s using some kind of hash algorithm on the device id (so all messages for a particular device go to the same channel).

Then, have a single-threaded poller pulling messages from each queue.

**EDIT:** (response to comment)

Again, difficult to generalize, but...

See `AbstractMessageRouter.determineTargetChannels()` - a router actually returns a physical channel object (actually a list, but in most cases a list of 1). So, yes, you can create the `QueueChannel`s programmatically and have the router return the appropriate one, based on the message.

Assuming you want all the messages to then be handled by the same downstream flow, you would also need to create a `<bridge/>` for each queue channel to bridge it to the input channel of the next component in the flow.

- create a `QueueChannel`
- create a `BridgeHandler` (set the `outputChannel` to the input channel of the next component)
- create a `PollingConsumer` (constructor takes the channel and handler; set `trigger` etc)

start() the consumer.

All of this can be done in your custom router initialization and implement `determineTargetChannels()` to select the queue.

Depending on the processing time for your events, I would generally recommend running the downstream flow on the poller thread rather than setting a `taskExecutor` to avoid issues with the next poll trying to schedule another task before this one's done. You might need to increase the default `taskScheduler`'s pool size.

Comment: Thanks - one of the things I'm trying to figure out is how do we do the "number of QueueChannels" and have the router identify the channel. From what I saw, the mapping is normally identified by channel IDs only. Do I have to configure one channel per device group or is there a way to programatically generate the channels?